# Getting weird error when trying to get simple test project and RavenDB to work together

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have downloaded https://github.com/JudahGabriel/RavenDB.ModernMvcStarterKit

My version is here https://github.com/Mech0z/Foosball9000

Downloaded the latest RavenDB RavenDB-Build-3528 and changed `NLog.ignored.config` to `NLog.config` to enable logging

If I start the application without having RavenDB running I get a request error (which is fine)

I then try again and get error that no database exists (again this is fine)

I have no trouble accessing Raven Studio and creating the database, but if I then start the RavenDB server and try again I get

> Could not figure out what to do
>
> {StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content:
>   System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: {   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Date: Fri, 02 Jan 2015 19:34:44 GMT   Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 }}

Nothing is written to the log file!

I have tried installing RavenDB and the project on 2 different machines and it gives me the same result on both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had Common Language Runtime exceptions to be thrown, disabled that and now it works

[image]